# Connection Timed Out - Db - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to connect to a db from my ec2 instance.  It works fine on my local-dev machine.  With the same credentials though on my ec2 instance it throws this error.  How would I bump up the timeout connection w/ CodeIgniter 3?:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 161

Backtrace:

File: /opt/workspace/api.my_app.com/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 500
```

Comment: Timeout isn't your problem. You don't have the right db config or you'd connect instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the places I would check:

- EC2 security group rules for IN traffic - it's possible your EC2 instance's IP address isn't being allowed, while your local-dev IP address is.  This is especially possible if you're using RDS - make sure port 3306 is open to IN traffic on the RDS from EC2's IP address.
- if MySQL is installed directly on the EC2 server (I wouldn't recommend this for large traffic use cases!), check your settings in application/config/database.php to make sure you're using the right credentials.  In this case, it kind of sounds like the DB HOST is misconfigured - if the IP address is wrong, it'll time out on the connection.

Comment: Perfect, yeah I was using the default inbound rules for RDS.  I ended up specifying the security group that my ec2 instance is on w/ port 3306 and that works.  Thanks!